# How do I use from security token for FIDO?

Tags: two-factor-authentication, fido-u2f, fido

I have a USB security token, that is used for generate key-pair and save secure data in it's memory.

Communication with this token is by c++ library. Like readMemory() and writeMemory() also genKeyPair().

I want to use this token in FIDO solution. What is way to connect the token and communicate with it?

I visit fidoalliance.org web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your token is not "open" (i.e. you cannot update its firmware) and if it is not a FIDO device (Yubikey, Feitian, ...), I'm afraid you can't.

If you can put some code in it, you will have to (at least):

- Implement [U2F HID protocol](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.2-ps-20170411/fido-u2f-hid-protocol-v1.2-ps-20170411.html) so that your token enumerates as a FIDO-HID device and communicates as such
- Implement [U2F messages](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.2-ps-20170411/fido-u2f-raw-message-formats-v1.2-ps-20170411.html) to answer U2F requests. The process of these messages may use your token API.
- [Test](https://github.com/google/u2f-ref-code/tree/master/u2f-tests/HID) it